# What is relation between the path fibration of classifying map and the Borel construction

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, classifying-spaces

I am trying to solve exercise 179 on [Davis-Kirk](http://www.indiana.edu/~lniat/m621notessecondedition.pdf):

> 1. Show that given a principal $G$-bundle $E\to B$, there is a fibration
>      $$E\hookrightarrow EG\times_G E\to BG$$
>      where $EG\times_G E$ denotes the Borel construction.
> 2. How is this fibration related to the path fibration $$P_f\to BG$$ 
>      where $f:B\to BG$ is the classifying map of the bundle $E\to B$?

The first part is trivial since $BG$ is a CW complex and we obtain a fiber bundle by Borel construction. The statement follows from the fact any fiber bundle over paracompact space is a fibration.

However, I have no idea what exactly does the second question mean. Should we construct a morphism between these two fibrations?

---

P.S.

The path fibration is given by the pull-back 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P_f @>>>  BG^I \\
@VVV @VVV \\
B @>{f}>>  BG
\end{CD}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p:E\rightarrow B$ be a principal $G$-bundle and consider the Borel construction  $EG\times_G E$. As you have found there is an induced map $\pi:EG\times_GE\rightarrow BG=EG/G$ with fibre $E$ obtained by projecting to the first factor. On the other hand, you can also project to the second factor to get a map

$$q:EG\times_GE\rightarrow B=E/G.$$

Since $p$ is a locally-trivial $G$-bundle the map $q$ has the structure of a locally-trivial fibre bundle with fibre $EG$. Moreover, since $EG$ is contractible, $q$ is a (weak) homotopy equivalence, which you can check by studying its long-exact sequence of homotoyp groups.

Therefore consider the following diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    G@>>> E @>p>> B\\
    @VV V   @VV  V@VV=V\\
    EG @>>> EG\times_GE@>q>\simeq >B\\
@VVV @VV\pi V\\
BG@>>=>BG
\end{CD}
which you can check commutes strictly. The top left-hand square is a pullback, which tells you that the fibre inclusion $E\hookrightarrow EG\times_GE$ of $\pi$ is a principal $G$-bundle. Since we know that $EG\times_GE\simeq B$, what we have achieved here is to construct an explicit classifying map for the bundle $p$, and at the same time have arranged for it to be a fibration. Namely the composite $\pi\circ q^{-1}:B\rightarrow BG$ is a classifying map for $E$, with $\pi$ a fibration. The point is that we have used only 'geometric' information to achieve this. Had we started with a map $f:B\rightarrow BG$ classifying $p$ and asked to understand its homotopy fibre $F_f$, this is exactly what we would have got.

To compare these two results directly choose a homotopy equivalence $\xi:EG\xrightarrow{\simeq}PBG$ and it together with the map $q$ to construct a map from the square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    E@>>> EG \\
    @VV V   @VV  V\\
    EG\times_GE @>\pi>> BG\\
\end{CD}
to the square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    F_f@>>> PBG \\
    @VV V   @VV  V\\
    B @>f>> BG\\
\end{CD}
Since both $q$ and $\xi$ are homotopy equivalences, the induced map of pullbacks $E\rightarrow F_f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have some questions: 1. Should "the top left-hand square is a pullback" be "the right-hand square"? Otherwise why can we say the inclusion is $G$-bundle?   2. since we use the inverse of $q$, why can we use this when $q$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, not a homotopy equivalence?   3. why $\pi\circ q^{-1}$ is the classifying map? I cannot draw the corresponding pull-back diagram...

Comment: I think I figure 2 out, but the rest is still unclear to me.

Comment: The top left-hand square in 1 is a pullback. The pull back along an identity map is an idenitity, so the top right-hand square cannot be a pullback. The inclusion is a $G$-bundle because diagram 2 is a pulllback. In diagram 2 you have that the canonical pullback consists of elements $([x,e],y)\in (EG\times_GE)\times EG$ with $xG=yG\in BG$. The second point $y$  gives you a representative for the coset so you can uniquely write $[x,e]=[y,e']$ for some $e'\in E$, and in this way get a map $EG\times_GE\rightarrow E$, $([x,e],y)\mapsto e'$, which is a homeomorphism. Hence the square is a pullback.

Comment: Of course the inverse to $q$ may not exist if $q$ is not a true homotopy equivalence, which is the reason I indicated that $q$ is only a weak homotopy equivalence without further assumption. Since classifying spaces are only defined up to (weak) homotopy equivalence anyway, see Theorem 9.15, where the existence of $EG$ is characterised by it being *weakly* contractible.
For reasonable groups you can assume that EG (and hence $B$ also) is CW. I introduce $q^{-1}$ really as an extra observation in this special case and you'll note that I don't refer to it at any other point.

Comment: $\pi\circ q^{-1}$ is *a* classifying map. These objects really only make sense up to homotopy, so it may not be a strict classifying map in the sense that $E$ actually is $(\pi\circ q^{-1})^*EG$, but rather $E$ is only bundle-isomorphic to this latter pullback. To see that it indeed is, you have that $\pi^*EG\cong EG\times_BE$ by square 2. Then since homotopy equivalences give you bundle isomorphisms you have $q^*((q^{-1})^*E)\cong E$ over $B$.